# Creating a prepared statement for PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

The is the current code I have:

```
$resultSet = $link->query("SELECT kudos.sale_id as TheID, kudos.ident_id AS TheIdent from kudos,sales_gdpr where kudos.sale_id = $id AND sales_gdpr.id = kudos.sale_id");
                                    
if($stmt = $link -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kudos WHERE sale_id=? AND ident_id=?")) 
{
    $stmt -> bind_param("is", $id, $myIdent);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($count);
    $stmt -> fetch();
    $stmt -> close();
}

if ($count == 0) { // Not liked
    echo "<a style='color:#FFFFFF' class='btn'>  $resultSet->num_rows </a>";
} else { // Has liked
    echo "<b style='color:#FFFFFF' class='btn'>  $resultSet->num_rows </b>";
}
```

The `SELECT COUNT` I have made as a prepared statement, but I can't figure out how to make the `$resultSet` as a prepared statement. The code works all fine as it is now, but because of the `kudos.sale_id = $id` part, I guess it it vulnerably to SQL Injection. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: Are you asking how to write a join clause with mysql?  ...I am pretty sure has HUNDREDS  of examples already.  You should avoid using the old-skool comma-joins because they are not easily read by other developers.  We need to see somple sample schemas and the expected result.

Comment: Hi, @mickmackusa. No, he actually thought that, in order to avoid sql injections, his sql statement (`SELECT kudos.sale_id...`) could be somehow prepared before calling the `mysqli::query` method, but he didn't know how to do it. At least that was my assumption when I wrote the answer based on the content of his SO question.

Comment: So are we talking about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51259779/2943403

Answer (score 1):

A code in which external values are **directly** passed into an SQL statement (like `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id = $id`) is open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql%20injection). In order to avoid them, an SQL statement receiving external values should always be prepared for execution. Terefore, the use of [mysqli::query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) should be avoided (since it doesn't allow any preparation).

Here are two examples on *"how to make the `$resultSet` as a prepared statement"*, depicting the two appliable methods for preparing an SQL statement in MySQLi, conditioned by the presence of [mysqlnd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) *("MySQL Native Driver")*.

**Method 1 - If *mysqlnd* driver is installed:**

This method uses [mysqli_stmt::get_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) and [mysqli_result::fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

In order to install the *mysqlnd* driver, the entry *"extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll"* (or similar) must be uncommented in the PHP config file (*"php.ini"*) and the web server must be restarted, along with the *mysql service*.

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

/*
 * Save the values, with which the database data will be filtered, into variables.
 * These values will replace the parameter markers in the sql statement.
 * They can come, for example, from a POST request of a submitted form.
 */
$saleId = 1;

/*
 * The SQL statement to be prepared. Notice the so-called markers,
 * e.g. the "?" signs. They will be replaced later with the
 * corresponding values when using mysqli_stmt::bind_param.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
 */
$sql = 'SELECT 
            k.sale_id AS saleId,
            k.ident_id AS identId 
        FROM 
            kudos AS k,
            sales_gdpr AS s 
        WHERE 
            k.sale_id = ? AND 
            s.id = k.sale_id';

/*
 * Prepare the SQL statement for execution - ONLY ONCE.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
 */
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

/*
 * Bind variables for the parameter markers (?) in the
 * SQL statement that was passed to prepare(). The first
 * argument of bind_param() is a string that contains one
 * or more characters which specify the types for the
 * corresponding bind variables.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
 */
$statement->bind_param('i', $saleId);

/*
 * Execute the prepared SQL statement.
 * When executed any parameter markers which exist will
 * automatically be replaced with the appropriate data.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
 */
$statement->execute();

/*
 * Get the result set from the prepared statement.
 *
 * NOTA BENE:
 * Available only with mysqlnd ("MySQL Native Driver")! If this
 * is not installed, then uncomment "extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll" in
 * PHP config file (php.ini) and restart web server (I assume Apache) and
 * mysql service. Or use the following functions instead:
 * mysqli_stmt::store_result + mysqli_stmt::bind_result + mysqli_stmt::fetch.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result
 */
$result = $statement->get_result();

/*
 * Fetch all data at once and save it into an array.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php
 */
$fetchedData = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

/*
 * ...or fetch and save one row at a time.
 *
 * @link https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
 */
// while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
//     $fetchedData[] = $row;
// }

/*
 * Free the memory associated with the result. You should
 * always free your result when it is not needed anymore.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php
 */
$result->close();

/*
 * Close the prepared statement. It also deallocates the statement handle.
 * If the statement has pending or unread results, it cancels them
 * so that the next query can be executed.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php
 */
$statement->close();

/*
 * Close the previously opened database connection.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php
 */
$connection->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            body { padding: 10px; font-family: "Verdana", Arial, sans-serif; }
            .result-set { border-collapse: separate; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
            .result-set thead th { padding: 10px; background-color: #f3f3f3; }
            .result-set tbody td { padding: 5px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h3>
            Result set
        </h3>

        <table class="result-set">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sale ID</th>
                    <th>Ident ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                if ($fetchedData) {
                    foreach ($fetchedData as $item) {
                        $saleId = $item['saleId'];
                        $identId = $item['identId'];
                        ?>
                        <tr class="result-set-record">
                            <td><?php echo $saleId; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $identId; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            No records found
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Method 2 - If *mysqlnd* driver is not/can not be installed:**

This method uses [mysqli_stmt::store_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php), [mysqli_stmt::bind_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) and [mysqli_stmt::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

$saleId = 1;

$sql = 'SELECT 
            k.sale_id AS saleId,
            k.ident_id AS identId 
        FROM 
            kudos AS k,
            sales_gdpr AS s 
        WHERE 
            k.sale_id = ? AND 
            s.id = k.sale_id';

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

$statement->bind_param('i', $saleId);

$statement->execute();

/*
 * Transfer the result set resulted from executing the prepared statement.
 * E.g. store, e.g. buffer the result set into the (same) prepared statement.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result
 */
$result = $statement->store_result();

/*
 * Bind the result set columns to corresponding variables.
 * E.g. these variables will hold the column values after fetching.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php
 */
$statement->bind_result($boundSaleId, $boundIdentId);

/*
 * Fetch results from the result set (of the prepared statement) into the bound variables.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php
 */
$fetchedData = [];
while ($statement->fetch()) {
    $fetchedData[] = [
        'saleId' => $boundSaleId,
        'identId' => $boundIdentId,
    ];
}

/*
 * Free the stored result memory associated with the statement,
 * which was allocated by mysqli_stmt::store_result.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php
 */
$statement->free_result();

$statement->close();

$connection->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            body { padding: 10px; font-family: "Verdana", Arial, sans-serif; }
            .result-set { border-collapse: separate; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
            .result-set thead th { padding: 10px; background-color: #f3f3f3; }
            .result-set tbody td { padding: 5px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h3>
            Result set
        </h3>

        <table class="result-set">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sale ID</th>
                    <th>Ident ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                if ($fetchedData) {
                    foreach ($fetchedData as $item) {
                        $saleId = $item['saleId'];
                        $identId = $item['identId'];
                        ?>
                        <tr class="result-set-record">
                            <td><?php echo $saleId; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $identId; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            No records found
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

**connection.php (included in both examples above):**

For details, [this article](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting) shows how to report errors in mysqli.

```
<?php

/*
 * This page contains the code for creating a mysqli connection instance.
 */

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'tests');
define('USERNAME', 'anyusername');
define('PASSWORD', 'anypassword');

/*
 * Enable internal report functions. This enables the exception handling,
 * e.g. mysqli will not throw PHP warnings anymore, but mysqli exceptions
 * (mysqli_sql_exception).
 *
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR: Report errors from mysqli function calls.
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT: Throw a mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
 */
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

/*
 * Create a new db connection.
 *
 * @see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php
 */
$connection = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);
```

**Notes / Suggestions**:

I didn't test the codes, but they should work.

I took the liberty to use my naming/coding conventions.

I strongly suggest you to switch from MySQLi to [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). [Here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) is a very good PDO tutorial.

You tried to apply some *error handling* by using `if($stmt = $link -> prepare(...)){...}`. Though, in order to be able to properly handle any kind of errors that may be raised by your present and future codes, I suggest you to read [this tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) thoroughly, along with all articles related to MySQLi found on that website.

And, at last, avoid printing (like with `echo`, for ex.) HTML code from PHP code, as much as possible. Try to separate PHP from HTML in a clean way. So, instead of something like this:

```
if ($count == 0) {
    echo "<a style='color:#FFFFFF' class='btn'>  $resultSet->num_rows </a>";
} else {
    echo "<b style='color:#FFFFFF' class='btn'>  $resultSet->num_rows </b>";
}
```

you could do this:

```
<?php
    //...

    $count = ...;
    $numRows = ...;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            body { padding: 10px; font-family: "Verdana", Arial, sans-serif; }
            .num-rows-link { color: #fff; background-color: #f3f3f3; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
            .num-rows-span { color: #fff; background-color: #f3f3f3; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
            if ($count == 0) {
        ?>
            <a class="btn num-rows-link"> <?php echo $numRows; ?></a>
        <?php
            } else {
        ?>
            <span class="btn num-rows-span"> <?php echo $numRows; ?></span>
        <?php
            }
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using the method 2, how can I get result-number of rows? I tried `echo $fetchedData->num_rows` but got error: `Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in / ...`

Comment: @Benedict Good question. I checked the code and I changed the line `$statement->store_result();` to `$result = $statement->store_result();` (in method 2). You can now apply `$numRows = $result->num_rows;` in method 2 as well, since `mysqli::store_result` returns a `mysqli_result` object - just like `mysqli_stmt::get_result` (from method 1). But you should thoroughly read these two docs when trying to get the number of rows: [mysqli::store_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) and [mysqli_result::$num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: Hm, weird. When I do `echo $result->num_rows;` it still gives me the same error: `Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in / `. What am I doing wrong? I am using the same code as in method 2.

Comment: @Benedict Before printing or assigning `$result->num_rows` to some variable you should check if the `$result` object is created at all, first. So, for testing purposes, right after `$result = $statement->store_result();` either call `var_dump($result); exit();`, or apply `echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';  exit();` to display the `$result` object on screen.

Comment: @Benedict It should look similar to this: `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0)`. Then you'll know where to start looking further. Again, it is important to read the two official documentation pages in-depth, e.g. [mysqli::store_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) and [mysqli_result::$num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).